# How do I add a button class based on a res.local variable in ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, express, ejs

I have buttons on a page. Some will be deactivated based on a res.locals variable. However, I can't figure out how to add a class using ejs. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
<button class="class1 class2 <% if (res.locals.myVariable === "a") { %> class3 <% } >" />
<button class="class1 class2 <% if (res.locals.myVariable === "b") { %> class4 <% } >" />
```

The first button would only have class3 if myVariable was set to "a", and the second button would only have class4 if myVariable was set to "b".

How can I do this? Is ejs the way to go or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your variable name which you defined with res.locals in your app. If you defined `res.locals.myVariable = somevalue;` then you can simply use myVariable like this:

```
<button class="class1 class2 <% myVariable === 'a' ? 'class3' : 'class4' %>" />
```